# Two UITableView on a View

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can i achieve following functionality.

I have a View, in that i want to add two `UITableView` as subView of that View..

1. `monthTableView`
2. `dayTableView`.

both tableView frame size is parent view size.

but only one table will visible at a time.
Example:

i need a method so when ever i called that method need to check which table view currently visible through flag variable.

```
if (visibleTable == monthTableView)
{

    //need to add subview of parent view is dayTableView
    [self addSubview:dayTableView];
}

if (visibleTable == dayTableView)
{

    //need to add subview of parent view is monthTableView.
    [self addSubview:monthTableView];
}
```

how can i achieve this.. kindly guide me. thanks in advance...

Comment: @user28882259 refer my answer. Definitely it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

In table view delegate methods, you will see a parameter `tableView` which is nothing but your current tableView. You can use that to distinguish between your tableViews.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == monthTableView)
    {
        //code for monthTableView
    }
    else if(tableView == dayTableView)
    {
        //code for dayTableView
    } 
    //extra coding
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate both tables by giving tag.i.e.

For first table view -

```
firstTableView.tag = 1;
```

For second table view -

```
secondTableView.tag = 2;
```

and in datasource and delegate methods differentiate table views by tag -

```
if(tableView.tag == 1){

    //do something

}else{

   //do something for send table view

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the "tag" value of both table view and then check the tag value using the following code:

```
if (tableView.tag == 0) {
    // tableView 1
}
else if (tableView.tag == 1) {
    // tableView 2
}
```

You can set the tag value in the interface builder or in the code as well. using setTag: method.

Answer (score 2):

You can Achive this by using a single tableview. what you need to do is using datasource and delegate methods to differentiate data for Day and Month. What can you do is use enum for table data one key is Day and second is Month. 
  Now in .h of controller

```
enum TableContentType {
  kDay   = 0,
  kMonth = 1
};


@property (assign) enum TableContentType tableContentType;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * monthDataArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * dayDataArray;
```

Now in .m file

the action to switch table content from Day to Month or vice-versa

```
- (IBAction)changeTableContent:(id)sender
{
   self.tableContentType  = (self.tableContentType == kDay) ? kMonth :  kDay;

   [self.table reloadData]; 

}
```

In the Table DataSource And Delegate methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return (self.tableContentType == kDay) ? self.dayDataArray.count :  self.monthDataArray.count ;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;



    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = (self.tableContentType == kDay) ? [self createDayCellForIndexPath: indexPath] : [self   createMOnthCellForIndexPath: indexPath];

    }

return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(self.tableContentType == kDay)
    {
       [self dayCellTappedForIndexPath: indexPath];
    }else
    {
       [self monthCellTappedForIndexPath: indexPath];
    }

}
```

Methods For Creating Cells for Given indexpath for day and month

```
- (UITableViewCell *)createDayCellForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
     UITableViewCell * dayCell = nil;
     // write your code for day cell here


   return dayCell;
}   

- (UITableViewCell *)createMonthCellForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
     UITableViewCell * monthCell = nil;
     // write your code for month cell here


   return monthCell;
}
```

Methods to perform cell selection actions for day and month

```
- (void)dayCellTappedForIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     // write your code for day cell tap

}

- (void)monthCellTappedForIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     // write your code for month cell tap

}
```

This will help you to mange the scenario that you have